# Detecting / avoiding g++ symbol collisions

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

Is there a way to detect and avoid if two shared libraries both expose the same global scope symbols?  We recently ran into a situation where we had `libA.so` that exported the `SuperCoolMethod()` and `libB.so` that also exposed the `SuperCoolMethod()` which would clobber the previous copy of said method.  This is on Linux using g++ 4.0 and later.  So in isolation if you link against `libA.so` everything would work as expected, but once `libB.so` was added to the picture the wrong method was called and the call would fail causing the executing thread to abort without notifying us of the potential problem.  Through exhausting trial and error we eventually found the `SuperCoolMethod()` getting clobbered and notified the vendor of `libB.so` so that the `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` can be applied to their copy of the method.

Answer (score 1):

As this is C++ the libraries each ought to be in their own namespace so collisions do no occur.

Comment: Ought to, but doesn't and it from a third party vendor.

Comment: If you can "notified the vendor of libB.so so that the __attribute((visibility("hidden"))" you can ask for namespaces which would work on non gnu compilers as well

Answer (score 0):

dynamically loading the library and attaching the symbols via dlopen and dlsym would work. You would have to write code to do it but if you were really truly stuck it would be a solution

Comment: Hmm, that might work since we never use the need to explicitly call the function in question, but it doesn't tell me how to discover the conflict to begin with.

Comment: a combination of nm and grep will tell you

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, if you only use one of the two methods, the order in which they appear on the **link** command line determines which version of the function you end up with in the final executable.

This isn't just an artifact, it's defined behavior, so you can depend on it (until the vendor fixes it).